# Predicate to fetch objects which parameter is contained in an specific NSSet

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicate, magicalrecord

I have following entities:

`PBOUser`, `PBOBusiness` and `PBOLocation`.

- `PBOUser` may have a lot of businesses.
- `PBOBusiness` may have a lot of locations.
- `PBOLocation` may belong to only one business.
- `PBOBusiness` may belong to many users.

I need to find these locations which belong to those businesses that my user owns.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "business IN %@", myUser.businesses)

let locations = PBOLocation.MR_findAllWithPredicate(predicate) as? [PBOLocation]
```

But it doesn't work. How to do this in a quick way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever wanted to do it as a query you would need to use a `SUBQUERY` predicate

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(business.users, $user, $user == %@).@count > 0", myUser)
```

- `business.users` is the keyPath to the collection whose elements you want to test
- Each item in the collection is evaluated agains the predicate `$user == %@`
- When each item is evaluated against the predicate we use `$user` to make that the variable name for the single element to use in the predicate

The `SUBQUERY` will return a collection of results that match so to summarise we use `@count > 0` to say if there was at least one match then this fits our criteria

Answer (score 0):

You could probably come up with a predicate that works. But since you already have a reference to `PBOUser`, you're making things harder than they need to be. Consider that

- `PBOUser` has a relationship to `PBOBusiness`
- `PBOBusiness has a relationship to`PBOLocation`

With these relationships, a user's businesses are `myUser.businesses`, as in your code snippet. So take that one step farther and use the fact that locations are a property of the businesses:

```
let locations = myUser.businesses.valueForKey("location") as NSSet
```

This makes use of the fact that `valueForKey` on an array or set will call `valueForKey` on each member of the collection, and return the results as the same kind of collection. That's why it's an `NSSet`-- if you want a sorted array, add a call to `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`.